# Using the Date variable in different formats within one module

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to set today's date and use it in different formats for various tasks, but I have no idea how to go about it. I know that `Date` is a global variable but it is in `2017-12-19` format on our system, for some tasks I'd need it to be `mm-dd-yyyy` or just `mm-dd` but I don't know how could I set this up without prompting the user to manually enter the date in said formats. Also can I use the `Date` variable just like a string or do I need to convert it?

```
Sub BasedOnDate()
Dim filename As String, Source As String, Destination As String
Dim myValx As String
Dim myVal1 As Date
Dim myValn As Date
Dim myFile As String
Dim myPath As String

'trying to declare today's date, but just the month and day as "mm-yy"
myVal1 = Date("mm-yy")
myValn = Replace(myVal1, "-", "\")

'trying to declare the date here in the desired format
myValx = Date("mm-dd-yyyy")

'File paths
Source = "\\Rdcicgtcuwd01p\app_log\36196_WMS\WMS_36196_PROD_" & myValx & ".csv"
Destination = "\\olscmesf003\gcm_emea\TCU_REPORTS\APPS\Reports\Regional\Workflow Management System\2017\" & myValn


FileCopy Source, Destination


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Format() function`:

```
myValx = Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy")
```

*Tip: Please keep in mind that `Format()` returns string, here it works fine, but could be a problem in other situation.*

Comment: so I could just use `myValz=Format(Date,"mm-dd")` if I'd only need the month and day from a date?

Comment: Alright this seems to solve the issue, I'll play around with it. I'll need to rewrite my 15+ module crazy ass macro now :D. Thanks a lot either way.